# Xcode Copy Files Build Phases

Tags: macos, file-io, frameworks, xcode5, wrapper

My project requires me to add multiple items to the Copy Files Build Phases. However, both files require different destinations. One of the items' destination is Frameworks while the other one is Wrapper.

If I fail to set each of their destinations properly, I get an error.

What I want to ask is that I have the Sparkle Framework to my project. According to the instructions from [Spark](https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/wiki), add it to the Copy Files and set the Destination to **Framework**. However, I am as well adding another item (Helper) to the Copy Files with a Destination that is to be set as **Wrapper**.
I can't seem to individually set the Destinations of both items.

Question #1:
Is there a way to set the Destinations of each item individually?

Question #2:
If there isn't, would it affect my app's behavior if I select either Wrapper or Framework for both items?

Comment: what error? how did you failed?

Comment: I don't understand the question; you understand that you need to correctly set the destination, so you know how to avoid the issue.  I think?!?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Copy Files phases, so make one for the Framework and another for the Helper.